# Kafka SSL handshake failed in custom Java producer

Tags: java, ssl, apache-kafka

Trying to produce some data using my Kafka producer application, but i get below error:

> [SocketServer brokerId=0] Failed authentication with localhost/127.0.0.1 (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

I use SASL_SSL protocol with PLAIN mechanism to communicate with Kafka. When I use kafka-console-producer
`sh kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic kafka-topic --producer.config ../config/producer.properties`

and kafka-console-consumer
`sh kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9093 --topic kafka-topic --consumer.config ../config/consumer.properties`

everything works fine. Here's a part of my **server.properties**:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SASL_SSL://localhost:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SASL_SSL://localhost:9093

listener.name.sasl_ssl.plain.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin-secret" \
   user_admin="admin-secret";

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer

allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=true

ssl.keystore.location=/mnt/data/kafka/config/keystore/kafka.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/mnt/data/kafka/config/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password

ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.secure.random.implementation=SHA1PRNG
```

**producer.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin-secret" \
   user_admin="admin-secret";
ssl.truststore.location=/mnt/data/kafka/config/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
```

**consumer.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9093
group.id=test-consumer-group
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
   username="admin" \
   password="admin-secret" \
   user_admin="admin-secret";

ssl.truststore.location=/mnt/data/kafka/config/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
```

And here's my Java Kafka producer application

```
private KafkaProducer<String, String> producer;
    private String address;
    private final int BATCH_SIZE = 16384 * 4;

    private Properties setProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, address);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, BATCH_SIZE);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 200);
        properties.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "snappy");
        properties.put("acks", "all");
        properties.put("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");
        properties.put("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        properties.put("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"admin\" password=\"admin-secret\" user_admin=\"admin-secret\";");
        properties.put("ssl.truststore.location", "/mnt/data/kafka/config/truststore/kafka.truststore.jks");
        properties.put("ssl.truststore.password", "password");
        return properties;
    }

    public void createTopicWithPartitions(String topicName, int partitionsCount) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, address);
        AdminClient adminClient = AdminClient.create(properties);

        boolean isTopicExists = adminClient.listTopics().names().get().stream()
                .anyMatch(name -> name.equals(topicName));

        if (isTopicExists) {
            System.out.println("Topic already exists");
        } else {
            NewTopic newTopic = new NewTopic(topicName, partitionsCount, (short) 1);
            adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(newTopic)).all().get();
        }

        adminClient.close();
    }

    public void sendMessages(String topicName, String payload, int messagesCount) {
        for (int i = 0; i < messagesCount; i++) {
            String partitionKey = DataUtils.generateSourceDeviceId(15).toUpperCase();
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topicName, partitionKey, payload));
        }
    }

    public KafkaMessagesProducer(String address) {
        this.address = address;
        this.producer = new KafkaProducer<>(setProperties());
    }

    public int getBATCH_SIZE() {
        return BATCH_SIZE;
    }
```

As I described before console producer/consumer works fine, my Java application gets SSL handshake error, but with switched off SASL_SSL protocol my Java app works fine.

**UPD**: Certificate generation tool used from this website:
`https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-platform-security-tools/blob/master/kafka-generate-ssl.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a problem with createTopicWithPartitions method. I rewrote properties created in setProperties() method by (AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, address)